# Question about proof of completeness theorem

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am reading a book about logic and in the proof of the completeness theorem there is a point I would like to clarify.

The part that is troubling me is the "easy" part, so basicly that $T \vdash F$ implies that $T \vDash F$.

In the book the author uses the natural deduction system. To prove this he takes $M$ to be a model of $T$ and he supposes that we have a proof of $F$ using the axioms of $T$ and proceeds by induction on the size of the proof.

In the induction he proves things for the rules associated to the symbols $\rightarrow, \land, \forall, \exists$ and says that we can use similar arguments for $\lor$, so far so good until here everything seems legit.
But after this he concludes the proof, and my problem is that he did not do any details for the symbol $\neg$ which bothers me. After this the author says that we obtain the following corollary: If $T$ has a model then $T \nvdash \bot$. This bothers me because when I try to prove the $\neg$ part in the completeness theorem I end up proving the corollary first. I will explain my idea bellow.

The rules I am using for $\neg$ are the following:

Rule 1:
From $\Gamma, A \vdash \bot$ we obtain $\Gamma \vdash \neg A$

Rule 2:
From $\Gamma \vdash \neg A$ and $\Gamma \vdash A$ we obtain $\Gamma \vdash \bot$

Rule 3:
From $\Gamma, \neg A \vdash \bot$ we obtain $\Gamma \vdash A$

And basicly I want to consider the last rule used in the proof is one of the three rules and show that the induction works. This is how I am thinking about doing it:

If the last rule is 2:

We may use our induction to prove that we must have that $M \vDash \neg A$ and $M \vDash A$ which is impossible by definition of $\vDash$. Thus this proves that if $T$ has a model then $T \nvdash \bot$. (this is the mentioned corollary above) Is this reasoning correct?

If the last rule is 1:

If we suppose that $M \vDash A$ then we would have $M \vDash T \cup \lbrace A \rbrace$, which means that $M$ is also a model for $T \cup \lbrace A \rbrace$. But this is not possible because we have $T \cup \lbrace A \rbrace \vdash \bot$ which means that $T \cup \lbrace A \rbrace$ does not have any model by the above discussion. Thus we cannot have $M \vDash A$, in other words we have $M \vDash \neg A$.

If the last rule used is 3 it is almost the same as for 1.

Could someone tell me if this reasoning is correct? Maybe I am over complicating simple things.

Comment: Maybe your book is using "$\neg P$" as an abbreviation for "$P\rightarrow\perp$"?

Comment: I don't think so because he explicitly introduces the rules 1, 2, 3 I mentioned. Anyways I think we would still have a rule related to $\bot$ and we would still need to deal with it in the proof.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but I don't understand your argument for Rule 2. You said that the statement "If $$ has a model then $⊬$" (I guess you omitted to say "for some formula $F$") is a corollary of the completeness theorem. So, you're not allowed to use it to prove the completeness theorem.

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking at a soundness proof ("provable statements are true") not a completeness proof ("true statements are provable"). Please help us to help you and name the book.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco It is because if we have $\Gamma \vdash \bot$ then the last used rule is 2, it means that you already have a shorter proof of $\Gamma \vdash A$ and $\Gamma \vdash \neg A$ and since these proofs are shorter we may use the induction to conclude that we have $\Gamma \vDash A$ and $\Gamma \vDash \neg A$. But this is not possible because by definition we cannot have both. So this means that $T$ cannot have a model or else we would have this problem. (And yes $F$ is some formula)

Comment: @RobArthan The book I am using is written in french so this is why I did not name it, it is "introduction a la logique" by "Réné David" at page 82. I am trying to prove the soundness theorem, but in the book the equivalence between truth and provability is called completeness, this is why I thought this what part of the completeness theorem.

Comment: I see. Completeness is usually defined to mean that true statements are provable, but your book doesn't seem to be following that convention. I think your ideas about how to fill in the details concerning negation are fine.

Comment: Re corollary, If F is a formula whatever, we have also $\bot$.

Comment: You have to check the rules for negation. Re rule 1, assume that the formula F is $\lnot A$ and it is derived using rule 1. But by ind hyp the above deriv is sound, that means that $\Gamma,A \vdash \bot$. But this implies that $M \nvDash \Gamma +A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally understood the solution.
So first of all as pointed out in the comments what I am trying to understand is the soundness theorem and not the completeness theorem.

The details I wrote for rule 2 is correct however I thought this also proves that if $T$ has a model then $T \nvdash M$ but this is not correct. Because I thought that if we have $T \vdash \bot$ the last rule used in our proof must be rule 2, but this is incorrect, for example we may choose $T = \lbrace \bot \rbrace$ we can very easily prove that $T \vdash \bot$ by using the axiom rule, thus not using rule 2. Thus the proof of my rule 1 is also incorrect because I was using this fact.

Here is how one can prove rule 1:

If our proof ends by rule 1, and $M$ is a model for $T$, by contradiction we can suppose that we have $M \vDash A$, since $M$ is a model we also have $M \vDash T$ thus we have $M \vDash T \cup \lbrace A \rbrace$. This means that $M$ is a model for $T \cup \lbrace A \rbrace$. And since to use rule 1 one needs to already have $T, A \vdash \bot$ thus a shorter proof of $T, A \vdash \bot$ which means that we can use our induction hypothesis to obtain that one has $M \vDash \bot$ but this is not possible thus we must have $M \vDash \neg A$.

(rule 3 can be proved in the same way.)

Thank you for all of your comments they helped me finding this solution.